# Magic behind idempotent-complete categories a.k.a. why (sometimes) be Karoubian is sexier than be Abelian

Tags: ct.category-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology, triangulated-categories

It is well know that  [Karoubian categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Karoubian+category) (also called  idempotent-complete categories) are living between additive and
Abelian categories. While one of the most famous advantages to
work with abelian cetegories is that they are closed under
building kernels and cokernels of arbitrary morphism, the
Karoubian categories have a slightly weaker property that only
*idempotent morphisms* (i.e. $p$ with $p^2=p$) from there share
this property.

Nevertheless it seems that in diverse constructions Karoubian categories
or Karoubian envelopes of additive categories provide a more
natural setting than Abelian categories.

I hope my question not becomes too broad: What is the philosophical
meaning behind Karoubian categories or say in simpler words why in some constructions they are  more prefered  (e.g.
category of pure motives and in K-theory) in contrast to say
at first glance more 'flexible' abelian categories?

My natural guess is that if we think about the construction
of of the category of pure motives we start with the category
of smooth varieties over a base field and pass after
application of this magic Karoubian completion functor to
idempotent-complete categories. Since it's not abelian it contains
by definition only kernel and cokernels of idempotent morphisms
but that's all we need there to proceed the constrution.

This lead me to conjecture that the main advantage of
Karoubian categories in contrast to Abelian categories mights show when
one have to perform a construction where one starts with
a certain preadditive category but the construction requireres
a category having at least some kernels and cokernels.

Now one can pass canonically to the Karoubian completion or
extend the initial category to an Abelian category. But exactly here I see
an obstacle with the secound and at first glance more 'natural'
approach:

Does there always a way to embedd a preadditive category in an abelian
category? If yes, seemingly the disadvantage of this approach
seems to be that this Abelian category is much harder to control,
while the Karoubian completion is constructed quite canonically and
behaves more 'similar' to initial preadditive category.

Questions: Is what I tried to sketch above exactly the motivation
why Karoubian categories are in some constructions more prefered
then Abelian categories?

Are there more reasons making Karoubian categories 'interesting'?
Is there any intuition or important example one should have in
mind how to think about Karoubian categories?

Comment: May be the basic example is the category of vector bundles which is Karoubian, but not abelian?

Comment: Karoubian categories are more abundant than abelian ones, but I don't  know if that makes them more interesting or in any sense preferred. By the way, although the category of Grothendieck motives is contructed as a Karoubian completion, one really wants it to be abelian...

Comment: @DonuArapura: 
So the philosophy here with Karoubian completion is indeed:
"Be satisfied with what you get", right? In case of pure motives
we obtain in a relatively easy way our Karoubian category after
completion which already have a lot of nice properties which an Abelian
category would have, but there is just no canonical way known to extend it to
an Abelian category, so that's a 'stay happy with what we have' philosophy? Then that's the whole moral?

Comment: @GhostinGrothendieckuniverse It's not a question of moral/philosophical principles, it's about what can be proved. If we stick to pure motives modulo homological equivalence, then Grothendieck conjectured this is abelian. However, I don't think anyone knows how to prove it. If we switch to motives mod numerical equivalence, then Jannsen did prove it's abelian.

Comment: Splitting idempotents has nothing at all to do with additivity or Abelianness. It's an easy construction that can be applied to **any** category at all. It's used in plenty of other subjects. For example it gives continuous lattices from algebraic ones and Scott-continuous maps.

Comment: @PaulTaylor Yes, but it seems OP is working in a Ab-enriched context. It's additivity (existence of direct sums) plus splitting of idempotents which is operative here: the absolute colimit completion.

Answer (score 21):

I don't know if this is going to answer your question but here's some relevant background. Splitting idempotents has a very special property from a categorical point of view: it is an [absolute colimit](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/absolute+colimit) (and also an absolute limit), meaning that it is preserved by any functor whatsoever. Two somewhat more familiar examples of absolute colimits, in enriched settings:

- In categories enriched over pointed sets (equivalently, categories with zero morphisms), zero objects are an absolute colimit. This also applies to $\text{Ab}$-enriched categories.
- In linear ($\text{Ab}$-enriched / preadditive) categories, (finite) biproducts are an absolute colimit.

In general we can ask for the completion of a (possibly enriched) category under absolute colimits; this is called its [Cauchy completion](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cauchy+complete+category) because it turns out to specialize to Cauchy completion when thinking of metric spaces as enriched categories. We have:

- For ordinary ($\text{Set}$-enriched) categories, the Cauchy completion of $C$ is given by splitting all idempotents, or equivalently by taking the full subcategory of the presheaf category $\widehat{C} = [C^{op}, \text{Set}]$ on the [tiny objects](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tiny+object) (objects such that $\text{Hom}(F, -)$ preserves all colimits; these turn out to be exactly the retracts of representables).
- For linear ($\text{Ab}$-enriched) categories, the Cauchy completion of $C$ is given by taking all formal direct sums and then splitting all idempotents, or equivalently by taking the full subcategory of the presheaf category $\widehat{C} = [C^{op}, \text{Ab}]$ on the tiny objects (these turn out to be exactly the retracts of finite direct sums of representables).

In particular, if we consider a ring $R$ as a one-object linear category $BR$, its Cauchy completion is exactly the category of finitely generated projective $R$-modules, which we famously use to define K-theory. This construction is a complete [Morita invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morita_equivalence) in the following sense: two rings $R, S$ are Morita equivalent (meaning $\text{Mod}(R) \cong \text{Mod}(S)$) iff their categories of finitely generated projective modules are equivalent (and this generalizes to enriched categories and Cauchy completions).

Cauchy completion is in some sense the "most harmless" and "most inevitable" completion: if you are ever going to apply a functor from your category $C$ to a category $D$ with colimits then every absolute colimit of objects in $C$ will appear in $D$ anyway (all idempotents will be split, etc.) so you might as well add them in first. Unlike the Yoneda embedding, which is the free cocompletion, Cauchy completion does not destroy colimits that may already exist in $C$. And because absolute colimits are preserved by all Hom functors $\text{Hom}(c, -)$, unlike adjoining colimits in general, the morphisms both into and out of an absolute colimit are already uniquely determined, so you have no choice how to do it anyway.

On the other hand attempting to write down some sort of completion of a linear category producing an abelian category seems quite tricky and potentially unwieldy. We can take the free cocompletion ($\text{Ab}$-valued presheaves) but again this destroys most existing colimits. Maybe the [Isbell envelope](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Isbell+envelope) has better properties but I don't know anything about it. Meanwhile the Cauchy completion is relatively easy to work with.

Comment: Qiaochu, you're on fire today. The first paragraph is exactly what needs to be said.

Comment: Sorry that I only now respond to your answer, I was quite bissy 
last days. One question: reading your answer I tried to understand
the deeper meening what it would mean if we pass a (pre)additive
category to it's idempotent completion. As you said then all 
idempotents would become absolute colimits and the point is at first 
glace how does it help. Abstractly, when passing to
idempotent completion we therefore obtain a new category containing a
distinguished class of morphisms
(the idempotents) which are all absolute colimits.

Comment: If we thinking
about concrete constructions of pure motives or $K$-theory then question
might be arise
why exactly this idempotent completion gives us a category which we need
as 'intermediate' step (because it has now enough structure)
to construct the final object/category we are looking for.

I don't know the $K$-theoretic construction good enough but recently
an analogy came into my mind which might draw a nearly similar 
picture.

Comment: Thinking about model categories these can be regarded as the 'most 
rigid category' where we can do homotopy theory. The main feature of
model category is that it contains enough classes of distinguished
morphisms ((co)fibirations, etc ...) to pass to homotopy theory.
Can our case with idempotent completion regarded fro simmilar point
of view: that this idempotent completion is some kind of 'most 
rigid category structure' (ie as in case of model category, a category 
with certain distinguished class of morphisms) which suffice
to 'build' a category/ an object we are looking for.

Comment: Is this the right way to think about this issue?

Comment: @Ghost: I'm afraid I don't really understand your question, in particular what you mean by "most rigid structure."

Comment: Sorry, i have noticed now that the word 'rigid' is here indeed misleading, 
replace everywhere where I  wrote it by 'most minimalistic 
structure or framework'. What I mean by it? 

If we recall again the analogy to abstract homotopy theory and model categories, 
then the essential question is which are the most
'minimalistic' requirements on a category we should
impose in order to 'do' there 'homotopy theory'? And as far s I understood
the issue there the answer is 'model category', essentially 
a category with a class of distinguished morphisms, that's all.

Comment: And my concern is if this 'philosophy' can exactly transfered to the concern
of this question, about for what we need the 
 Karoubian category (or why if we start with some additive cat we should pass
to idempotent closure). So the question is if here 'Karoubian category' 
plays the 'role' of model category, but now instead to do
homotopy theory there, we want associate to a category a $K$-theory or 
a category of motives in most natural way.

As you wrote in Karoubian category all idempotents are absolute colimits,
and drawing the analogy to homotopy & model cat's one can

Comment: simply think it as a cat + class of distinguished morphisms, so we have again the similar
situation as above: Karoubian category = cat + class of distinguished morphisms.

So one can ask if Karoubian category is a sort of 
'most minimalistic structure' (ie that's all what we should require,
but it's all neccessary) to which we can associate a $K$-theory 
or a motivic category directly, ie it's some kind of smallest neccessary and 
sufficient framework to build $K$-theory or motivic category from it, like 
a model category

Comment: is a most minimalistic framework to do
homotopy theory there. Hope, that it's not a too confusing attempt to explane

Comment: @Ghost: I don't really feel like I have anything intelligent to say about this question.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to comment that idempotent completion is sometimes the right thing to do 'by design'. (I don't have enough rep to just leave a comment though.) I'm reminded of the category of motives, in which you would like to have some kind of 'cellular decomposition' of your varieties, the archetypical example being that one would like the motive $[\mathbb{P}^1]$ to split as $[\mathbb{A}^1] + [\text{pt}]$ or something along those lines. Idempotent completion does exactly that: it forces the idempotent map $\mathbb{P}^1 \to \operatorname{Spec} k \to \mathbb{P}^1$ to have a kernel, which leads to the desired decomposition.

Comment: Yes; of course, passing to these idempotent completions sometimes we indeed obtain the category we 'need' to develop 'good' theory like in the case of motives as you said. But my concern aimed primarily not at 'that' we obtain a category with which we can better work, but 'why' exactly this 'idempotent completion' gives the desired catogory where it's better to work. Up to now by Qiaochu Yuan's and Todd Trimble's answer / comment in all theories where the construction involves passing to idempotent completion the category which meets allmost all our requirements has to have

Comment: enough distinguished classes of morphisms, which are absolute colimits. The initial additive category might also have certain absolute colimits, but seemingly not enough. It's like in case of model categories, which have distinguished class of morphisms which suffice to also to do there homotopy theory. That's at least how I understood Qiaochu Yuan. (the analogy to model category came recently to my mind)